# Connect to WCF host through socket

Tags: c#, sockets, wcf

I need to write my own client to read data from existing WCF host which is using TCP protocol.

My idea is to create socket, connect to remote host and communicate through that socket.

Here is code that I am using

```
//this part works well

NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://MY_ADDRESS:6334/IESI");

ChannelFactory<IIESIRemote> factory = new ChannelFactory<IIESIRemote>(binding, address);
IIESIRemote remote = factory.CreateChannel();

IESIState state = remote.State;

((IClientChannel)remote).Close();
factory.Close();

//this part does not work

IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("MY_ADDRESS").AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 6334);

Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

socket.Connect(ep);
```

When I use traditional WCF client - everything is normal. But when I am trying to connect using socket I recieve "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Could you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's somewhat easier to use `TcpClient` by the way particularly if you are going to use streams

Comment: WCF's `net.tcp` protocol is not trivial to write a client for. It's actually a rather complicated protocol (think: it's like SOAP-over-HTTP, but in binary). You're going to have an upwards-hill fight. Why can't you use Visual Studio's service proxy generation tools instead?

Comment: @Dai - because I need to get access to remote WCF host from HoloLens device and I just cannot force traditional ChannelFactory<> to work there.

Comment: That brings up an interesting point - you `shouldn't be using NetTcpBinding with non-Windows platforms`. https://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric/dp/0596805489.  NetTcpBinding should only be used on a Windows LAN with Windows clients on both ends.